# Iterate through array of IDs and modify corresponding elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array called `requiredIDsUnique` which contains ID numbers:

```
["13000", "13003", "13003", "13007"]
```

These numbers correspond to the `data-solutionid` attribute of elements like so:

```
<div class="solutionitem hide" data-solutionid="13000">
    <h4>Solution 1</h4>
    <p>Some description for Solution 1.</p>
</div>
```

I want to iterate through the array, and remove the `hide` class from each `solutionitem` class element who's `data-solutionid` corresponds to an ID in the array.

I have tried modifying several code snippets I found but I am unable to achieve what I want to do.

Comment: elem.getAttribute("data-solutionid") == value and also elem.classList.contains("hide"); If you know how to run conditions this should fair nicely and not need much explaination.

Comment: [jQuery attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a data attribute selector and call `removeClass`.

Something like this...

```js
const ids = ["13000", "13003", "13003", "13007"];

ids.forEach(id => {
  $(`.solutionitem[data-solutionid="${id}"]`).removeClass('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .hide { display: none; }
</style>

<div>
  <div class="solutionitem hide" data-solutionid="13000">
    <h4>Solution 13000</h4>
    <p>Some description for Solution 13000.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="solutionitem hide" data-solutionid="13003">
    <h4>Solution 13003</h4>
    <p>Some description for Solution 13003.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="solutionitem hide" data-solutionid="13007">
    <h4>Solution 13007</h4>
    <p>Some description for Solution 13007.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="solutionitem hide" data-solutionid="13010">
    <h4>Solution 13010</h4>
    <p>Some description for Solution 13010.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vanilla JS version using `Array.from`

```js
let ids = ["13000", "13003", "13003", "13007"]

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-solutionid]')).forEach(div => {
  if (ids.includes(div.dataset.solutionid)) div.classList.remove('hide')
})
```

```css
.hide {
  opacity: .4;
}
```

```html
<div class="solutionitem hide" data-solutionid="13000">
  <h4>Solution 1</h4>
  <p>Some description for Solution 1.</p>
</div>
<div class="solutionitem hide" data-solutionid="13003">
  <h4>Solution 2</h4>
  <p>Some description for Solution 1.</p>
</div>
<div class="solutionitem hide" data-solutionid="13300">
  <h4>Solution 3</h4>
  <p>Some description for Solution 1.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You could easily avoided using indexOf inside a forEach

Comment: @moustafa - thx. changed to `.includes()` - open to better ideas...